# SQL command to insert two primary keys into third table

Tags: sql

I have two tables, Job(JID, agency) and Agency(AgID, Agency). And I want to create a third table Job_Agency(JID, Agid). How do I insert data into job_agency?

Here is my info.

so the job table is the original table, it contains job id, agency, salary, desc etc, but it is not normalized. So i created job_agency and agency tables. job_agency have jid and agid, for one agid, there are many jid assigns to it. I have done with agency table. for the job_agency table, i want each jid match to the right agld.

Comment: `insert into Job_Agency` ?

Comment: Can you supply sample data and desired results?  As written, this doesn't make very much sense.  Do you want to insert all job/agency combinations into the new table?  How do they relate?

Comment: Ok, so the job table is the original table, it contains job id, agency, salary, desc etc, but it is not normalized. So i created job_agency and agency tables. job_agency have jid and agid, for one agid, there are many jid assigns to it. I have done with agency table. for the job_agency table, i want each jid match to the right agld.

Answer (score 0):

Create table with following structure: (Make your 3rd table the first table)

```
JOB_AGENCY
    combo_id --> Primary Key
    JID
    AgID


JOB
    JID   --> Primary Key for this table referencing JID of JOB_AGENCY
    JobDesc


Agency
    AgID  --> Primary Key for this table referencing AgID  of JOB_AGENCY
    Agency
```

Insert records as usual using "INSERT INTO" statements. Make sure that you first insert into the JOB_AGENCY table and then into JOB and Agency tables

Comment: hi, the job table is the original data table. so in job table, i have jid, agency. I created agency table. Now i need to create a job_agency table.

Comment: Then simple. Make JOB-JID and Agency-AgID as primary key. Make JOB_AGENCY-JID and JOB_AGENCY-AgID as foreign keys. Always, primary keys should be inserted first and then the referencing primary keys should be inserted.